# Retrieve Documents using wildcard "like" in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have some documents which tittle are :

```
DocumentTitle: "119053_L048.pdf" , DocumentTitle: "119052_L048.pdf , DocumentTitle: "119029_L048.pdf , DocumentTitle: "119239_L048.pdf , DocumentTitle: "119314_L048-2.pdf" , DocumentTitle: "119310_L048-2.pdf" , DocumentTitle: "Application.pdf , DocumentTitle: "Abstract.pdf , DocumentTitle: "Drawing.pdf
```

and I want to retrive the documents using elasticsearch query which titles are ends with **"_L048.pdf"**. In sql The query is like :

```
SELECT * FROM documents_table where DocumentTitle like '%_L048.pdf';
```

I have tried the below elastic serach query

```
URL:http://localhost:9200/document/_search?size=10000
```

Post Data:

```
{
 "_source":["DocumentSubtype","DocumentTitle","CaseID","ApplicationNumber","OpenToPublic"],
  "size" : 0,        
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "query": "OpenToPublic:true AND DocumentTitle:*_L048.pdf"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}

But it returns zero result :

{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello, please join your mappings

Comment: Could you change your search term to lowercase? So: "DocumentTitle:*_L048.pdf" to "DocumentTitle:*_l048.pdf". Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hello , i tried with "DocumentTitle:*_l048.pdf" , but still it is returning zero result.